# Pass input values of one view in service URL of another view SAP UI5

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I created two views- view1:

> [image]

and view2:

> [image]

And set input's values as Json model in View1Controller and navigate to view2.

```
onInit: function() {

        oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        
    },

    onPress1: function(oEvent) {

        if (typeof(sales) != 'undefined' || sales != null) {
            
            oModel.setData({
                "myData":{
                "sales": sales,
                "cust": cust,
                "appl": "LEVEL1"    
                }   
            });
            
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
        
                var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
                oRouter.navTo("header");

        } else {
            alert("Please select Sales Person..")
        }
    },

    sChange: function(oEvent) {
        sales = this.byId("salesPerson").getValue().split(",").pop();   
    },
    cChange: function(oEvent) {
        cust = this.byId("customer").getValue().split(",").pop();
    }
```

In view2Controller i received the view1 input's data and created a Json model and i want to create a table in view2 based on view1 input's data.

```
 function(Controller, JSONModel, History) {
"use strict";
 var level, sales, cust;
return Controller.extend("dashdashboard.controller.View2", {

    onInit: function() {
       
           var oModel= sap.ui.getCore().getModel(oModel);
           
           level = oModel.getProperty("/myData/appl");
           sales = oModel.getProperty("/myData/sales");
           cust = oModel.getProperty("/myData/cust");
           
         
    }
```

Now i am having services URL-- `sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSD_DASHBOARD1_SRV/ZAPPROVALSet(APPLEVEL='LEVEL1',CUSTOMER='',SPERSON='00000009')/SO_HeaderSet`

for this URL i need to pass all three values so i used like this-

```
ZAPPROVALSet(APPLEVEL='"+level+"',CUSTOMER='"+cust+"',SPERSON='"+sales+"')/SO_HeaderSet
```

Please tell me how can i bind this path two my view2 Table.
it is giving me errors.

```
<Table items="{ path: '/ZAPPROVALSet(APPLEVEL='"+level+"',CUSTOMER='"+cust+"',SPERSON='"+sales+"')/SO_HeaderSet', sorter: { path: 'vbeln' } }" inset="false" id="idProductsTable">
```

Please Help.

Comment: You can't reference to variables in your XML without using a model. I would suggest to load the data of ZAPPROVALSet/SO_HeaderSet in your controller code from your oData default model object (https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/read). Store the result in a new controller JSONModel and then bind your xml table to that JSONModel. This way you are more flexible than binding the xml table to the default model directly.

Comment: I tried to set URL as Json Model. this.myURL = "ZAPPROVALSet(APPLEVEL='"+level+"',CUSTOMER='"+cust+"',SPERSON='"+sales+"')/SO_HeaderSet";
            var oViewModel = new JSONModel({myURL: this.myURL});
            this.getView().setModel(oViewModel,"view");

Comment: And access in view--                                                                                                   <Table items="{ path: '/{view>/myURL}', sorter: { path: 'vbeln' } }" inset="false" id="idProductsTable">

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this problem. We should send Parameters while Routing from one view to another and use RoutePatternMatched concept. And finally use .read() in _onRoutePatternMatched function to resolve it.

And here we can get values from prameters and pass our framed URL after putting those values in URL properly.

you can refer [simple-exercise-on-odata-and-sap-ui5-application](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/02/05/simple-exercise-on-odata-and-sap-ui5-application-for-the-basic-crud-operation/)

```
 Call oDataModel.read( pass_your_framed_url_here , { 
    success: function(receivedData){
         //set the received data to local json model and bind that to the view
    } });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use so form of [Expression Binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html) with this. (Don't forget to set data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex" in the UI5 bootstrap !)

```
<Table items="{ path: '{= '/ZAPPROVALSet(APPLEVEL='$(viewModel2>level}',CUSTOMER='$(viewModel2>cust}',SPERSON='$(viewModel2>sales}')/SO_HeaderSet'}', sorter: { path: 'vbeln' } }" inset="false" id="idProductsTable">
```

Is there a reason, why you transfer the data from View1 to View2 via Json Model and not via [Routing Parameters](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/2366345a94f64ec1a80f9d9ce50a59ef)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a read but a cleaner way would be to do an element binding with expand in the pattern matched handler and do the bindings when data is received.

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3900020